# nested select in Phalcon's query builder

Tags: sql, phalcon

I have two tables ,  Website and user_website_map

I want to select Websites with nested select condition

Code  is this

```
$query = \Website::query()->addWhere('id in (SELECT user_website_map.website_id from security.user_website_map where user_id = :userId )', [':userId' =>  $this->getId()]) ;
        return $query->execute();
```

This statements throws exception

```
Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Exception: Syntax error, unexpected token SELECT, near to ' user_website_map.website_id from security.user_website_map where user_id = :userId )', when parsing: SELECT [Website].* FROM [Website] WHERE id in (SELECT user_website_map.website_id from security.user_website_map where user_id = :userId ) (138)
```

If i execute this query from db console no error occures.

```
SELECT  * FROM main.website WHERE  id in (SELECT user_website_map.website_id from security.user_website_map where user_id = 2)
```

For information I am using postgresql-9.4 and Phalcon 1.3.4
What is wrong with this statements ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query could--and should--be accomplished with a join rather than a sub-query:

```
$query = \Website->query()
    ->join('UserWebsiteMap') // replace with actual model name
    ->where('user_id = :user_id:', array('user_id' => $this->getId()));
```

While I am more familiar with MySQL than with PostgreSQL, I believe it is true for both databases that sub-queries have a negative impact on performance, relative to joins. See the following link for an explanation of why: [Join vs. sub-query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-sub-query).

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that join queries has more performance than subqueries.